# Javascript null input error

Tags: javascript, html, validation

i have this input field

```
  html +='<p style="font-size: 18px; ">Total Bids: <input type="text" class="total_bids" name="total_bids" placeholder="No. of Bids" required></p>';
```

and the button

```
html += '<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="'+onclick_url_bid_o_matic+'" class="btn-bidoo" id="btn-bidoo">Activate</a>';
```

i get thie value of the input field via

```
var totalbids = document.getElementsByName('total_bids')[0].value;
```

if a user enters a number, it works fine, but if a user does not enter anything and press the activate button, it gives this error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

i want to restrict user to enter something, i already applied required in the input field but that did not work,(i dont know why) any other check with which i can restrict user to enter something?

EDIT:

I get this value in php and i have applied a check there too,

```
 $total_bids = PSF::requestGetPOST('totalbids');

if(!$total_bids)
        {
            return json_encode(array('error' => 'enter a number'));
        }
```

but it does not reach till here, as it stops with the null value error

the button leads to this function

```
bid_o_matic:function(id, uid, e, evt){

            var totalbids = document.getElementsByName('total_bids')[0].value;
            var bidval = document.getElementsByName('bidvalue')[0].value;


            parent_element = $(e).parent().parent();


            if(typeof(evt) != 'undefined'){
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
            }
            if(e.attr('disabled') == 'disabled'){
                return;
            }
            e.button('loading');
            $.post('index.php', {
                page:'__request',
                module:'PSF_auctions',
                action:'make_bid_o_matic',
                id:id,
                uid:uid,
                totalbids: totalbids,
                bidval: bidval
            }, function(d){
                e.button('reset');
                document.getElementById("btn-bidoo").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById("btn-deactivate").style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById("totalbids").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById("bidvalue").style.visibility = 'hidden';

                if(d.error){
                //        document.getElementById("totalbids").style.visibility = 'visible';
                // document.getElementById("bidvalue").style.visibility = 'visible';
                     $.auctions.alert(d.error);
                    document.getElementById("btn-bidoo").style.visibility = 'visible';
                    document.getElementById("btn-deactivate").style.visibility = 'hidden';

                }
                else
                {
              $(current_price_element).html('<p style="color:#f47321; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">Current Price</p><a href="#">'+d.bid_value+'</a>')

                }

            }, 'json');
        },
```

and the error occurs in this line

```
 document.getElementById("totalbids").style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: You don't read/write to `style` property anywhere in provided code.

Comment: I thin'k the error is on another place. Because in your code you're not accessing to `Style` attribute

Comment: i dont, i simply get the value user enters via getelementsbyname

Comment: Can you post code for function `onclick_url_bid_o_matic`

Comment: @wonderbell just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens Because `total_bids` is the `class` of your input not the `id`. You don't have any `id` called `totalbids`. When you try to find an object with `id` like `totalbids` you found nothig. To solve it change your input like this.

`<input type="text" id="totalbids" class="total_bids" name="total_bids" placeholder="No. of Bids" required></p>`

or use

`document.getElementsByName('total_bids')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden'`

Comment: @ShailendraSharma I think it is the right answer. The OP is trying to access element by` id` at the line of error. See the EDITED question. `document.getElementById("totalbids").style.visibility = 'hidden';` Rest of the places, it is access by Name. Please take a moment before casting negative vote. @Faizan please try this answer.

Comment: yup, my bad. i did not provide the id.

Comment: @wonderbell document.getElementById("totalbids").style.visibility = 'hidden'; written in success block and as mentioned in question  "if a user enters a number, it works fine" could you EXPLAIN  That ?

Comment: @ShailendraSharma yes it works fine, it sends the number to the php code as desired, this document.getElementById("totalbids").style.visibility = 'hidden'; is meant to HIDE this input field, and has nothing to do with the working, btw it did not hide this input field wither, in my case the problem WAS that i did not mention Id.

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"  was should be there in  works fine case that make lot of scene

Answer (score -1):

Because you doing it in wrong way. You actually posting your form to server side by using HYPERLINK

```
html += '<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="'+onclick_url_bid_o_matic+'" class="btn-bidoo" id="btn-bidoo">Activate</a>';
```

This is wrong way to submit the form. replace it with your actual input submit button. Then it will validate your text-field

```
    html += '<input type="submit" class="btn-bidoo" id="btn-bidoo" value="Activate" />';
```

and set **onclick_url_bid_o_matic** URL on your form tag

```
html += '<form action="' + onclick_url_bid_o_matic + '" method="post">'
```

Or if you still want to use hyperlink tag, then submit your form with the help of Javascript/Jquery

That's why you getting NULL in the requested URL

Comment: The call reach the code inside function. yout answer has not sense

Comment: The question he provide, generating HTML code with the help of Javascript. Then trying to post the form by clicking hyperlink tag. which is not valid. Thats why HTML5 validation not working.